# Determining Highest Number

Tags: java

I am writing a program where the user must input 10 numbers and the output should be the highest number on the 10 inputs. But I don't know what's the next code that I will write.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class kzz {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

         int a = 1;
         int value ;

         while (a < 11) {
             System.out.print("Enter Value No." + a + ":");
             value = reader.nextInt();
             a++;
         }
     }
}
```

What should I do now?

Comment: You need to check if the current number is greater than the previous number.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the first value into `value`, fine. Say it was 86. Next time through the loop you are reading the second value into *the same* variable, thereby overwriting the first. So the 86 are gone forever.

Instead I suggest a second variable `highestValueSoFar`. Store into it the value read only if it is higher. Then at the end this will contain the highest of the 10 values.